# Field Day Schedule (8 Teams and 8 Games)

Tags: graph-theory

Need to figure out schedule for company field day.  We have 8 teams, with 8 games to play.  Each team should play each game only once.  Can repeat teams faced, but not more than twice and no team should play the same game twice.

Comment: Is there anything you're trying to optimize or are there any other conditions? Otherwise, this seems fairly trivial. An easy way to think of this is to just split the eight teams into two groups of four teams each, have each team from the first group play a game from the second group, then cycle through the teams until you've covered every match up between the two groups. Then you just cover all of the matchups within each group. Only $4$ games are being played at once, so it should be fairly easy to avoid having a team play a game twice.

Comment: it's not possible. for team 1, there are 7 different opponents so when team 1 plays game 8, you have to use one of the 7 which means some teams have to play the same game more than once.

Comment: @Vasya That just means it is required to repeat opponents, not games.

Comment: I'm realizing now that "each team should play each game only once" means exactly once, not only once. Even so, I think it should still possible, albeit a little harder, since as Mike said, a team can play the same team twice, just not more than twice.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: No, eventually you will run out of pairs.

Comment: Yes, teams should play each game only once.  you can repeat team matchups, but not games

Comment: Would this be possible if we went down to 7 teams or 7 games?

Comment: Does each team have to play every round?  I haven't been able to see how to do this if there are $8$ rounds with $4$ matches each, but I have an idea if there can be $9$ rounds, some of which will have fewer than $4$ matches, of course.

Comment: We could do a "Bye" if needed.  Would prefer to drop a game versus add a round (just for time).

Comment: Got it figured out with 8 teams, 7 games:

Comment: Here's a schedule for 7

games, with each match in the format "[game]:[team 1][team 2]":

1    1:12 2:45 3:36 4:78
2    2:13 1:47 5:58 6:26
3    3:14 2:68 5:37 7:25
4    4:15 1:38 5:24 7:67
5    5:16 3:57 4:23 6:48
6    6:17 1:56 3:28 7:34
7    7:18 2:27 4:46 6:35

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Hold the phone!  I found a mistake in my script.  My method worked.  Here's my solution:

```
Round 1
Team 1 vs. Team 2 in game G
Team 7 vs. Team 8 in game B
Team 3 vs. Team 4 in game C
Team 5 vs. Team 6 in game A

Round 2
Team 1 vs. Team 2 in game D
Team 5 vs. Team 6 in game H
Team 3 vs. Team 4 in game E
Team 7 vs. Team 8 in game F

Round 3
Team 1 vs. Team 3 in game A
Team 2 vs. Team 4 in game F
Team 6 vs. Team 8 in game D
Team 5 vs. Team 7 in game G

Round 4
Team 2 vs. Team 3 in game H
Team 6 vs. Team 7 in game E
Team 5 vs. Team 8 in game C
Team 1 vs. Team 4 in game B

Round 5
Team 4 vs. Team 8 in game A
Team 2 vs. Team 6 in game C
Team 1 vs. Team 5 in game E
Team 3 vs. Team 7 in game D

Round 6
Team 1 vs. Team 6 in game F
Team 2 vs. Team 5 in game B
Team 4 vs. Team 7 in game H
Team 3 vs. Team 8 in game G

Round 7
Team 4 vs. Team 6 in game G
Team 1 vs. Team 7 in game C
Team 3 vs. Team 5 in game F
Team 2 vs. Team 8 in game E

Round 8
Team 4 vs. Team 5 in game D
Team 3 vs. Team 6 in game B
Team 1 vs. Team 8 in game H
Team 2 vs. Team 7 in game A
```

I attacked this in two stages; first I came up with a schedule of which teams played against each other in what rounds, by the manner described below.  Then I tried to assign sports to the matches with the "dancing links" algorithm with the following constraints:

1. Each match is assigned exactly one sport
2. Each team plays every sport
3. No sport is played twice in the same round

Here is a description of how I built the schedule.  It's very ad hoc.  I don't know offhand how to generate more schedules to test.

Represent the teams as elements of $Z_2\oplus Z_2\oplus Z_2$, and consider the addition table as indicating what round the two teams will meet.  If $a+b=c$ that means that teams $a$ and $b$ meet in round $n_c$ where we've numbered the elements.  Since the group is commutative, the table is symmetric, and we have no conflicts.  Since since every element has order 2, all teams "play themselves" in the same round.  So, instead of this round, we just just pair off the teams.  That gives a schedule where each team plays every other team once, and exactly one team twice.